# diff cmd, Binary files x and y differ

Tags: c, file-io, diff, pipe

I have a program that takes two files as an argument.  The first file is to be copied into the second.  The program forks into 2 children, the first child reads file and throws it thru the pipe to the other, then the other child writes it out to a file.  The two files are supposed to be identical in the end.

When I run diff to compare the two files I get the following error:

```
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ ./parent test.txt test2.txt
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ cat test.txt
123456789112233445566778899
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ cat test2.txt
123456789112233445566778899
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ diff test.txt test2.txt
Binary files test.txt and test2.txt differ
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$
```

As you can see they are both the same, but the diff prints out that they are different.  Obviously its just something I don't understand about the diff cmd.  Any help would be appreciated.

I believe for some reason the file I create is a binary file whereas the first file is not, but I am unaware as to why it is a binary file.  I believe it might have to do with this line of code:

```
    write(1, buf, BUF_SIZE);            //write to buffer
    memset(buf, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
```

In one of the children this is writing out to the buffer then I am clearing the buffer.  Am I clearing out that buffer wrong?

Here is the result of cat -e:

```
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ cat -e test2.txt
123456789112233445566778899$
^@^@^@^@virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$
```

Here is the result of cmp:

```
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$ cmp test.txt test2.txt
cmp: EOF on test.txt
virtual@ubuntu:~/Documents/OSprojects$
```

I believe that is my problem, how can I clear out that buffer so it doesn't throw those at the end?

ALL OF MY CODE::

Parent:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

void exitWithError(char* errorMsg, int exitWith);       //generic error out function
void launch_writer(const char* pathname, char* const argv[], int pfd[]);    
void launch_reader(const char* pathname, char* const argv[], int pfd[]);   

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

//making the pipe
int pfd[2];
if(pipe(pfd) == -1) //test pipe creation
    exitWithError("PIPE FAILED", 1);

//forking
pid_t reader_child_pid;
pid_t writer_child_pid;

//args for each fork
char *args_1[] = {"reader", argv[1], (char *) 0};
char *args_2[] = {"writer", argv[2], (char *) 0};

if((writer_child_pid = fork()) == -1) {
    exitWithError("WRITER FORK FAILED", 1);
}
else if (writer_child_pid == 0) {       //first child comes here
    launch_writer("./writer", args_2, pfd);
}
else if ((reader_child_pid = fork()) == -1) {
    exitWithError("READER FORK FAILED", 1);
}
else if (reader_child_pid == 0) {       //second child comes here
    launch_reader("./reader", args_1, pfd);
}

//parent picks up here

//close off pipe from parents end
close(pfd[0]);
close(pfd[1]);


//wait for all processes to exit before ending
for(;;) {
    if(wait(NULL) == -1){
        if(errno == ECHILD)
            exit(0);
        else {
            exitWithError("WAIT ERROR", 1);
        }
    }
}
}

void exitWithError(char* errorMsg, int exitWith) {
perror(errorMsg);
exit(exitWith);
}

void launch_writer(const char* pathname, char* const argv[], int pfd[]) {
dup2(pfd[0], 0);
close(pfd[1]);
close(pfd[0]);
execve(pathname, argv, NULL);
perror("execve failed");
}

void launch_reader(const char* pathname, char* const argv[], int pfd[]) {
dup2(pfd[1], 1);
close(pfd[1]);
close(pfd[0]);
execve(pathname, argv, NULL);
perror("execve failed");
}
```

Child 1:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//Opens file to be read from
int inFile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

//declaring variables
char buf[BUF_SIZE]; //temp hold whats read/written
int read_test;      //check if EOF
for(;;) {
    read_test = read(inFile, buf, BUF_SIZE);    //read from file
    if(read_test == 0) //eof
        break;
    write(1, buf, BUF_SIZE);            //write to buffer
    memset(buf, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
}
close(inFile);
exit(0);
}
```

Child 2:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//Opens a file for reading/writing, if exists then truncates, otherwise makes new one
//with correct permissions
int wri_inFile = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if(wri_inFile == -1)
    perror("ERROR OPENING FILE");

//declaring variables
char buf[BUF_SIZE];  //to store what is read in/written out
int read_test;      //test if EOF
for(;;) {
    read_test = read(0, buf, BUF_SIZE); //read from buffer
    if(read_test == 0) //eof
        break;
    write(wri_inFile, buf, BUF_SIZE);   //write to file

}
close(wri_inFile);
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Create a hex dump of the files. They are probably different because of some invisible character/control character at the start or end of the file.

Comment: Try `cat -e` to see if there's any non printable character. My bet is that there would be a `\0` at the end of the second one.

Comment: What happens if you use `cmp` instead of `diff`?

Comment: The title of the question sounds like you want to understand `diff` a little better, but reading the question makes it seem like you want to find out why your `c` code is incorrect. Post all your code if your question is the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check (and use) the read data length. Therefore, your data gets padded with garbage.

There should be actual data bytes read (`read_test`):

```
read_test = read(0, buf, BUF_SIZE); //read from buffer
if(read_test == 0) //eof
    break;
write(wri_inFile, buf, BUF_SIZE);   //write to file
-----------------------^^^^^^^^
```

The same applies to the other child. You should also check the error conditions.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I don't know why I did what I did, but your suggestion fixed it right up.  Diff now displays that both files are the same.  Thanks again.